# Djongo ArrayField in Django Admin Panel Error

Tags: python-3.x, django, mongodb, django-admin, djongo

Whenever I try to go to the product details page I encounter this error -

`'list' object has no attribute '_meta'`

How to solve it?

My models

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,
                        db_index=True,
                        unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    category = models.ArrayReferenceField(
        to=Category,
        blank=True,
        related_name="products"
    )
    def get_categories(self):
        return "\n".join([p.name for p in self.category.all()])
```

admin

```
@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name','price', 'in_stock','get_categories',)
```

I'm using
Django - 3.1.7 ,
djongo - 1.3.4

Comment: viewset and form please?

Comment: @Neeraj I'm trying to build a Rest API. Their doc says no form needed. https://www.djongomapper.com/using-django-with-mongodb-array-field/